# Is it possible to force `expect` to `puts` a string of nulls without a newline?

Tags: tcl, expect

Consider the following script, which I'll call `PrintNull.tcl`.

```
puts -nonewline "\0\0\0\0"
```

If I run this script with `tclsh`, it outputs the four null characters as expected:

```
tclsh PrintNull.tcl  | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000
```

If I run this script with `expect`, it outputs nothing:

```
expect -f PrintNull.tcl  | xxd
# No output at all
```

Curiously, if I modify the script slightly and remove the `-nonewline`, both `tclsh` and `expect` behave the same way, but now they both have an extra newline character:

```
expect -f PrintNull.tcl  | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000 0a                             .....
tclsh PrintNull.tcl  | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000 0a                             .....
```

**What is causing this behavior, and is it possible to force expect to behave like tcl when processing `puts`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly flushing stdout can solve the issue:

```
$ expect -c 'puts -nonewline "\0\0\0\0" ' | xxd
$ expect -c 'puts -nonewline "\0\0\0\0"; flush stdout' | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000                                ....
```

Based on the observation stdout is line-buffered for both Tcl and Expect but seems like Expect does not flush stdout before exiting.

**NOTE:** The issue is not specific for NULL chars. For example `expect -c 'puts -nonewline foobar'` can also reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did more experiments, and I found that both `send` and `send_user` seem to work fine for printing nulls in `expect`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

send "\0\0\0\0"
send_user "\0\0\0\0"
```

Output:

```
./PrintNull2.exp  | xxd
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

I'm still interested in any answers that explain why `expect`'s version of `puts` appears to be broken though.

Comment: Expect replaces `puts` with it's own version. Always has done; I guess it dates back to the early days (before Tcl had a good `puts` of its own; Expect is *that* old!) and has been kept that way because someone somewhere has a script that depends on it.